# Issue in getting token using PowerBI

Tags: content-testing

We are upgrading from Sitecore 8.2 to 9.3, and working on validating the PowerBI reporting features in 9.3. While validating, we got an issue as mentioned below:

```
AADSTS90002: Tenant '' not found. This may happen if there are no active subscriptions for the tenant. Check to make sure you have the correct tenant ID. Check with your subscription administrator.
```

But the subscription is working fine in 8.2 and able to see the reports in it.

In 9.3, we have upgraded the dll `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` from 3.19.5 (3.19.50615.2240) to 5.2.2.0

Could anyone please suggest does this dll affects in acquiring token and please suggest us on which version of dll do we need to use for Sitecore 9.3?

Comment: Maybe you need to go through the breaking changes in v4 and/or v5 and then make that change inorder to resolve this issue ? See here - https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/1346#issuecomment-625342344

Comment: Release notes for each version are here - https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki#roadmap